# HttpClient.PostAsync Xamarin.Android C# wrong response

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-core, httpclient

I am writing an Xamarin.Android app that posts data to Net Core web app with ADAL authentication. The problem is that the API controller is set so it does not require authentication ([AllowAnonymous]), but one and only one of my  httpClient.PostAsync() methods responds with the Microsoft Login page. I have tried to use WebClient.UploadString() and the response is the same Login page. I am porting this app from UWP and the same code works there without any problem.

Edit:
Adding some code for more information. The problem is that response.IsSuccessStatusCode is true, but the responseString contains the Microsoft Login page, but it should come back with json data.

```
  HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {


            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new System.Net.Http.StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            return result;
        }
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            try
            {
                //parsing the response
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               //response was incorrect
            }
        }
```

Comment: post your code for better understanding... with urls

Comment: I think the problem is with API controller not the xamarin app.  It looks like you are calling the rest service properly

Comment: The odd part is that it is not working only from Xamarin Android app. I Have tried from an emulator and from actual device and the response is that i need to sign in, but when i post data form UWP app and Fiddler it works fine and doesn't ask for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
HttpContent content = response.Content;
var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```